# SQL query to return average of results using JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a simple manufacturing job card system that track parts and labor for an assigned job.

It consists of a **JobHeader** table that holds the Job Card number (*JobHeader.JobNo*), ID of the part being manufactured (*JobHeader.RegNo*) and quantity to be manufactured (*JobHeader.RegNo*).

There is a child table (*JobLabour*) that tracks all the times that have been worked on the job (*JobLabour.WorkedTime*)

I'm looking for a query that will return the average time taken to produce a part accross the last 5 job cards for that particular part.

The following query

```
SELECT TOP 5 JobHeader.RegNo, JobHeader.BOMQty, sum(JobLabour.WorkedTime) AS TotalTime FROM JobHeader INNER JOIN JobLabour ON JobHeader.JobNo=JobLabour.JobNo
WHERE JobHeader.RegNo='RM-BRU-0134' 
GROUP BY JobHeader.BOMQty, JobHeader.JobNo, JobHeader.RegNo
```

will return this:

[image: Current result]

But what I'm looking for is a query that will return the average **BOMQty** and average **totalTime**. Something like this:

[image: Required result]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `AVG instead of `SUM`?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I highly recommend, short, table aliases.

Comment: To get the last 5 cards, won't you need an order by a date column?

Comment: How is "last 5" determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this will do the work
this will work for 1 RegNo='RM-BRU-0134'  at a time

```
with topFive as (
    SELECT TOP 5 JobHeader.RegNo, JobHeader.BOMQty, sum(JobLabour.WorkedTime) AS TotalTime
    FROM JobHeader
    INNER JOIN JobLabour ON JobHeader.JobNo = JobLabour.JobNo
    WHERE JobHeader.RegNo = 'RM-BRU-0134' 
    GROUP BY JobHeader.BOMQty, JobHeader.JobNo, JobHeader.RegNo
)
select RegNo, avg(BOMQty) as BOMQty, avg(TotalTime) as TotalTime 
from topFive 
group by RegNo
```

Comment: @DonalMcNamee . . . This answer is not correct.  It averages 5 indeterminate rows rather than the last 5.

Comment: I answer to the best of my ability there was no column to order the data by for a better answer additional info is require

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I added the line **ORDER BY JobHeader.JobNo DESC** just after the **GROUP BY** in the inner query. As JobHeader.JobNo is a sequential number, it returns the last 5 most recent records ordered by JobNo's.

Answer (score 1):

Your question explicitly mentions the "last five" but does not specify how that is determined.  Presumably, you have some sort of date/time column in the data that defines this.

In SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select jh.*, jl.*
from jobheader jh outer apply
     (select top (5) avg(BOMQty) as avg_BOMQty, avg(totalTime) as avg_totalTime
      from (select top (5) jl.*
            from joblabour jl
            where jl.regno = jh.regno
            order by jl.<some datetime>   -- however you determine the last five
           ) jl
      ) jl;
```

You can add a `where` clause to the outer query to filter on one or more particular jobs.